# Asp.Net set format text for DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist that display DateTime object in default format.

I want that visible date is in format "ddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
like :  Mon 13/08/2013 21:30

Using this code :

```
ddl_dat.DataTextFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}";
```

it work but show me only : 13/08/2013

Using instead

```
ddl_dat.DataTextFormatString="{ddd 0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}";
```

I have a FormatException

Comment: does `{0:f}` or `{0:D}` also fullfill your needs? The only drawback is, that it writes the full month instead of a numeric value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one:

```
ddl_dat.DataTextFormatString="{0: ddd d/MM/yyyy HH:mm}";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<asp:DropDownList id="yourList" runat="server" dataTextFormatString="{0: ddd d/MM/yyyy HH:mm}"/>
```